# how to fix weird drag behavior?

Tags: d3.js

Here is the simplified code:

```
this.x.domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.x));
this.y.domain([ 0, d3.max(data, d => d.y) ]);

svg.selectAll('circle')
           .data(data)
           .enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr('cx', d => this.x(d.x))
           .attr('cy', d => this.y(d.y))
           .attr('r', 4)
           .attr('class', 'circle')
           .style("fill", "white")
           .style("stroke", "steelblue")
           .style("pointer-events", "all")
           .style("stroke-width", "2px")
           .call(d3.drag()
                   .on("start", dragStarted)
                   .on("drag", dragged)
                   .on("end", dragended));

function dragStarted( d ) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed("active", true);
}

function dragged( e ) {

            let yLocation = d3.event.y;
            e.y           = y.invert(d3.mouse(this)[ 1 ]);

            console.log(e);
            d3.select(this)
              .attr("cy", yLocation);

            // update(data);

    }
```

The problem is when I first drag the circle, the circle gets positioned at the upper extent of the chart. The circle just goes up. How can I make sure that the dragging starts from the original position of the circle without that shift?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding this to `d3.drag()`:

```
d3.drag().subject(function () {
     let t = d3.select(this);
      return { x: t.attr("cx"), y: t.attr("cy") 
};
```

This will fix the original position without the jump.